# parallax scrolling | let image fly in when you scroll

Tags: parallax

there are many website that have the "parallax" scrolling effect. But I would like to start simple by letting various images fly in as I am scrolling down.

A simple illustration:

[image: illustration]

The image will actually fly in as the user is scrolling (start flying in on visible, on scroll), but I'm okay if the image fly's in directly when the image is visible to the user (trigger fly in on visible)

How can this be accomplished? Are there any demo's, library's, tutorails etc. available? Is there a specific name for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of great parallax tools available. If you are looking for tutorials, my company and I list some at http://potentpages.com/parallax-tutorials/

Some of the main methods used to create parallax websites are:

- Javascript (without any libraries)
- jQuery (and libraries that go on top of jQuery like Stellar.js)
- Skrollr.js
- Jarallax
- CSS (without any javascript)

My company also created a quick and simple tutorial on how to create a parallax tutorial with javascript (no extra libraries needed) at http://potentpages.com/parallax-scroll-tutorial/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<body>
 <div id="section1"><h1>section1</h1></div>
 <div id="section2"><h1>section2</h1></div>
 <div id="section3"><h1>section3</h1></div>
  </body>
```

css:

```
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}
 #section1{ width: 100%; height: 650px; background: url("http://www.wallsave.com/wallpapers/1280x960/abstact-red/186157/abstact-red-abstract-balls-186157.jpg");}
 #section2{ width: 100%; height: 650px; background: url("http://wallpaper-fun.ophibian.com/wallpapers/wallpaper_08.jpg");}
 #section3{ width: 100%; height: 650px; background: url("http://wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Technology-Wallpaper-6.jpg");}
 h1{ color: chartreuse; text-align: center; line-height: 650px;} 
 #section2 h1{ color: #fff;}
```

js:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $( window ).scroll(function() {
 var val = $(window).scrollTop();
 $("#val").text(val);
 $("#section1").css({"background-position":"-"+val*2+"px 50%"});
 $("#section2").css({"background-position":"50% -"+val*2+"px"});
 $("#section3").css({"background-position":val*2+"px 50%"}); });
 </script>
```

follow this way to help you to create and understand about parallax website

http://learning-day.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-create-own-parallax-website.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/create-a-funky-parallax-background-effect-using-jquery/

I prefer to use lazyload for your problem, so the image will be loaded when it reaches the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Add an eventlistener for page scrolling and when one of these object become visible, animate them. This can be implemented with jQuery like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.flyIns').each(function(i, element){
        if($(element).offset().top < scrollTop + 400){
            $(element).animate({left:'50px'}, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you having a look at Skrollr.js. It has a very good documentation and your effect can be accomplished with Skrollr.js very easily.

Have a look at these two tutorials to help you get started:

- [Simple parallax scrolling tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)
- [How to create a parallax scrolling website](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/)